# How to GET/POST SharePoint list/library data out side of SharePoint?

Tags: angular, rest, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, pnp-js

I need to POST data in the SharePoint list from outside of SharePoint. I have created an Angular application and I need to POST data in the SharePoint list using the Angular application with REST API or PnP/JS.

Can anyone help me with the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use two approaches:

Using register an app in SharePoint and using ClientId and ClientSecret to authenticate.
Ref.: [Authorization Code OAuth flow for SharePoint Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/authorization-code-oauth-flow-for-sharepoint-add-ins)

USE MSAL Library to authenticate. If I'm not wrong there is an example using Angular to authenticate.

Ref.: [Overview of the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview)